# left click GetAsyncKeyState getting stuck

Tags: vb.net

So I'm coding this project that has a `CheckBox` that makes it so if that the `CheckBox` is checked, it starts a `Timer` and that `Timer` gets the state of left click. For some reason, when I tap left click, the `asynckeystate` picks it up and then it starts `Timer` 1, for some reason when I tap it, it SOMETIMES get stuck even though I already let go of left click.

Can anybody help?

```
If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
    Me.KeyPreview = True
    Timer3.Enabled = True
Else
    Me.KeyPreview = False
End If

End Sub
Private Sub Timer3_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
    hotkey = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LButton)
    If hotkey = True Then
        Timer1.Start()
    Else
        Timer1.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It does not return a Boolean.  Do consider using the [built-in .NET method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousebuttons(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) instead.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you somehow edit my code and make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it seems to work fine, the only thing that may be the cause is the timer's interval being too high. If you wanted the events to fire only when the mouse button was pressed or released, I slightly modified your function and added a boolean to check if the mouse button was already down or released.

```
Private Sub Timer3_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Static LeftMouseButtonDown As Boolean = False
    Dim hotkey = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LButton)
    If CBool(hotkey) = True Then
        ' Timer1.Start()
        If Not LeftMouseButtonDown Then
            LeftMouseButtonDown = True
            Console.WriteLine("Left mouse button was pressed.")
        End If
    Else
        ' Timer1.Stop()
        If LeftMouseButtonDown Then
            LeftMouseButtonDown = False
            Console.WriteLine("Left mouse button was released.")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I hope this helped!
~Nic